# How do I display the menu-bar in emacs every time I start up?

Tags: emacs, menubar

I put this in my .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables                                                                          
 '(gud-gdb-command-name "gdb --annotate=1")
 '(large-file-warning-threshold nil)
 '(menu-bar-mode t)
 '(shell-dirtrack-verbose nil))
(custom-set-faces                                                                         
 )
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Note the `(menu-bar-mode t)`. When I fire up emacs, I have to `M-x menu-bar-mode` to get a menu bar. I am running GNU Emacs 22.1.1 (mac-apple-darwin, Carbon Version 1.6.0)

Comment: You should consider upgrading to the latest GNU Emacs: http://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: I do get a menu bar with Emacs 22.2.1 on Linux and exactly what you posted in `.emacs`. So either you have something else in your `.emacs` that turns off the menu bar or it's a Mac/Carbon-specific issue.

Comment: I tried people's suggestions below; they didn't work, but when I purposely put a bug in the .emacs file so that it wouldn't load all the way (I didn't close a paren) then the menu-bar appeared. Weird. What's the load order for emacs? Are there other default locations that a system-wide .emacs file is being loaded?

Comment: Running `emacs -q` exhibits this same behavior.

Comment: default.el (usually located in a site-lisp directory if it is present) is loaded after .emacs, but running emacs -q should stop that.  Most likely it is something else specific to the (mac-apple-darwin, Carbon Version 1.6.0) build.

Comment: @phils If you make that one of the answers (below) I'll give you the points! :) I upgraded my emacs install and the code works. :)

Comment: Done. Glad to hear it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider upgrading to the latest GNU Emacs:

[emacsformacosx.com](http://emacsformacosx.com)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the associated function says:

```
With a numeric argument, if the argument is positive,
turn on menu bars; otherwise, turn off menu bars.
```

So you could try `(menu-bar-mode 1)` instead of `(menu-bar-mode t)`

That said, for me (Emacs 23.2.1), setting this via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` `menu-bar-mode` results in the same entry in my custom-set-variables as you show there, and it has the desired effect when I restart.

There could be a difference between versions of Emacs, though. Did you type that manually? The recommendation is to only use the `customize` interface for making changes, as making a mistake might break things. Or possibly one of your other settings is invalid?

(In Emacs 23.2.1 I can't customize a `gud-gdb-command-name` or `shell-dirtrack-verbose` variable, for instance. OTOH I would presume it's still possible to customize variables from libraries which are only loaded on demand, so this probably doesn't mean anything.)

You could comment out everything else in your customize-variable if you wanted to check this (but watch out for that final closing parenthesis :)

Comment: Confirmed: `C-u 1 M-x menu-bar-mode` -> Menu-Bar mode enabled

Comment: I tried everything you suggested (modifying the invocation, commenting out other customizations, etc). I'm using the `customize` interface to edit these things, but none of these suggestions worked. It may be a bug with the specific implementation/platform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `(menu-bar-mode 1)` belongs inside of `custom-set-variables`.  Instead, put it outside, just like your call to `add-hook`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(gud-gdb-command-name "gdb --annotate=1")
 '(large-file-warning-threshold nil)
 '(shell-dirtrack-verbose nil))
(custom-set-faces
 )
(menu-bar-mode 1)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Comment: Have you tried invoking emacs with "-Q" (assuming that's even possible on OS X)?  That will prevent all startup files from loading; if it makes emacs appear with a menu-bar, then you know that some startup file was -preventing- the menu-bar from appearing.  I'd try it myself but don't have access to a Mac.